# Is it possible to add parameters dynamically in jax-ws web-service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am exposing a jax-ws web-service to client with two parameter(say FirstName,LastName) initially.Say after some times we need to change the web service with 3 parameters(Say FirstName,LastName,FatherName), How do we add the new parameter without stopping the service(or server where the web server running).

I want to have the parameters in a property file(or in DB). If I add new parameter in that property file then the web-service needs to be updated.

Is it possible to add parameters dynamically in jax-ws web-service? please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the fields dynamically but you can use some approach to reach the same result.

- Using a List of KeyValue object like interface argument, in this way the client will call the ws adding the keys/values needed.
- Providing a ws where the input is a standalone xml so you will be able to unmarshal it and do what you need.

Advantages:
You have not to change your interface if a new field is added but only the backend.

Disvantages:
You have to check the key syntax to be sure of the reliability of the input.

Comment: Bit of a hack, but I like the first suggestion. Would a Map be more suitable though?

Comment: Yes, Now we are receiving values as JSON String, Map also be more sutiable

Comment: @LiamDempsey Webservice should be interoperable,  HashMap is not. You can use an adapter which tells to JAXB runtime how to convert the map into an xml structure and I think this would be the same of first approach.

Comment: Do we have any other options to receive values as Map and display the keys in wsdl file?. Is there any possibility to add a parameter in wsdl file without code change?  and These newly added parameters need to be displayed in the WSDL file

Comment: @Java_Dinesh No you can't add dynamically parameters without code change and modifying only the wsdl; you can use the approach I explained. If you want to provide to the client the keys you could expose another service returning all the keys accepted and then use them to create the input for the approaches in the answer. In this way you can read the keys from a DB table and insert / delete what you want (but this is not safe since the old clients could call the ws with some parameter you deleted; you will always notify the client if something has to be changed. This is the only way if you don'

Comment: @WebMethod(operationName = "insertRecord")
 public String insertRecord(
   @WebParam(partName = "userName", name = "userName") String userName,
   @WebParam(partName = "password", name = "password") String password). is it possible to change the partName in the annotation dynamically?

Comment: @Java_Dinesh I really don't understand what you don't understand about "you can't".

Answer (score 0):

I really want to say "you can't"... I can't think of anything to allow this (others might).

What I will say instead is "you shouldn't". Thinking about the client code when you suddenly change the interface of a web service, the WSDL changes and client code will need to be regenerated.

(Just to clarify, *adding* a new method in a WS would be fine, altering one that exists is much more troublesome.)